# video-js problem in vuejs component. class="video-js" is loading after play button is pressed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, html5-video, video.js

i am developing a laravel-vuejs website. i have installed videojs using npm and also tried to use cdn of videojs, but the problem is same for both. design of any videojs video player is not loading at first place. after pressing the play button, design of videojs video player is loaded, the design get changed after play button is pressed. screenshots are attached here. if anybody finds solution, please let me know.

from App.js

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
window.videojs = videojs;
```

from VueComponent

```
<video id="currentIntroVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" width="350" height="260" @timeupdate="onTimeUpdateListener($event)" data-setup='{}' controls preload="auto">
                            <source v-bind:src="'/'+axiosGetIntroVideo" type="video/mp4">
                            <p class="vjs-no-js">
                                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
                                web browser that
                                <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
                                >supports HTML5 video</a>
                            </p>
                            
                        </video>
```

**1. the design of video player when the page is loaded**

[image]

**2. the design of video player when the play button is pressed. i want this design when the page is loaded**

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what your goal is.  Based on your two screen-shots, I'm wondering:  Are you just wanting the video to start auto-playing, so that the user doesn't have to hit any 'start button'? You do say "...after the button is pressed", but your 2nd picture is showing that the big-play start button has NOT been pressed.

Comment: first picture is the current state of the design when the page is loaded. when i click the play button from the first picture, the video get started and play for 1-2 seconds and then the design of the video gets changed and currentTime of the video become zero and the design of the video becomes what i showed in picture 2. but thankfully i got the solution. the solution is i need to call a function "videojs(videoId/videoRef)" when metadata is loaded. when videojs() function is called i get the design (from picture 2) what i wanted when the page is loaded.